# Mysql - priotize alphabetical sorting over numeric

Tags: mysql

I am creating a pick and pack list for a new wagon system, for this route to be optimal i need to sort the SKU list by the order our product rows are in. The first letter, or the first two letters indicate the position in our warehouse.

So having this list from sorting like this:

```
ORDER BY IF(sku RLIKE '^[a-z]', 1, 2), sku ASC;
```

```html
+-------------+
| sku         |
+-------------+
| A3-1-1195   |
| A3-1-1195   |
| AA6-8-7117  |
| AB10-7-6405 |
| AB10-7-6405 |
| AB4-4-3487  |
| AB5-6-3460  |
| AB6-3-3445  |
| C1-8-5623   |
| K1-4-1835   |
| O7-7-4737   |
| O8-7-4344   |
| O8-7-4344   |
| U1-8-6664   |
+-------------+
```

Edited:

My ideal result would be if all numeric sorting is prioritized first, then numbers. Here is the catch though, if the second char is a number, it should be sorted in alphabetical desc.

```html
+-------------+
| sku         |
+-------------+
| AB4-4-3487  |
| AB5-6-3460  |
| AB6-3-3445  |
| AB10-7-6405 |
| AB10-7-6405 |
| AA6-8-7117  |
| A3-1-1195   |
| A3-1-1195   |
| C1-8-5623   |
| K1-4-1835   |
| O7-7-4737   |
| O8-7-4344   |
| O8-7-4344   |
| U1-8-6664   |
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to split your field into 5 fields:
 np = size of your position field
 position = position char(s)
 n1 = first number
 n2 = second number
 n3 = third number

and sonrt with these fields.
heres a example with no table connection (for testing in a query browser with your data):

```
SELECT
    sku,
    MID(sku, 1, np) AS position,
    REPLACE(MID(sku, np+1, 2), '-', '') AS n1,
    REPLACE(MID(sku, np+3, 2), '-', '') AS n2,
    REPLACE(MID(sku, np+5, LENGTH(sku)), '-', '') AS n3
FROM (
    SELECT
        IF(MID(sku, 2, 1) REGEXP '[0-9]', 1, 2) AS np,
        s.*
    #subquery for this test
    FROM (
        SELECT 'A3-1-1195' AS sku
        UNION ALL SELECT 'A3-1-1195'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'AA6-8-7117'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'AB10-7-6405'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'AB10-7-6405'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'AB4-4-3487'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'AB5-6-3460'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'AB6-3-3445'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'C1-8-5623'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'K1-4-1835'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'O7-7-4737'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'O8-7-4344 '
        UNION ALL SELECT 'O8-7-4344'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'U1-8-6664') as s
) AS s
ORDER BY np DESC, position, n1, n2, n3
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! :-) I've updated my goal to reflect that second character should be sorted in alfabetical desc. if a number.